# Using Spring boot with rest controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

Main class:

```
package com.rsc.springboot_test;
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootTest.class, args);
    }
}
```

Controller Class:

```
package com.rsc.springboot_test_controller;
@RestController
public class testController {

    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public void home() {
        System.out.println("@@@Home Controller Called");
    }
}
```

POM file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>springboot_test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>springboot_test</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <jjwt.version>0.7.0</jjwt.version>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>${jjwt.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.yaml/snakeyaml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
            <version>1.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.mobile</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-mobile-device</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Its a simple spring boot app with rest controller.

Calling `http://localhost:8084/springboot_test/` loads the default index.html page

The problem is when I call `http://localhost:8084/springboot_test/home` it is not printing the output `System.out.println("@@@Home Controller Called");` so I guess the request is not called on rest controller itself. But why it isn't called?

**Update**

Using the `@ComponentScan("com.rsc.springboot_test")` on rest Controller as suggested by @javaguy works but I want to apply the @componentScan on top of main class so that it scans all packages on startup.

Trying the following gives error:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.rsc.*" })
public class SpringBootTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootTest.class, args);
    }
}
```

Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@58f7ff2f: startup date [Wed Nov 09 21:08:20 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:404) [spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationListenerDetector.postProcessBeforeDestruction(ApplicationListenerDetector.java:97) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:253) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:578) [spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:554) [spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:954) [spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:523) [spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961) [spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]


2016-11-09 21:08:20.765 ERROR 8500 --- [o-8084-exec-402] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.rsc.springboot_test.SpringBootTest]; nested exception is org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException: Annotation-specified bean name 'testController' for bean class [com.rsc.springboot_test_controller.testController] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [com.rsc.springboot_test.controller.testController]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:180) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:324) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:246) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:270) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:93) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_102]
Caused by: org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException: Annotation-specified bean name 'testController' for bean class [com.rsc.springboot_test_controller.testController] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [com.rsc.springboot_test.controller.testController]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.checkCandidate(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:320) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:259) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanAnnotationParser.parse(ComponentScanAnnotationParser.java:137) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:268) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:230) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
09-Nov-2016 21:08:21.046 SEVERE [http-nio-8084-exec-402] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/springboot_test]]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:197) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:166) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    ... 61 common frames omitted

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.rsc.springboot_test.SpringBootTest]; nested exception is org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException: Annotation-specified bean name 'testController' for bean class [com.rsc.springboot_test_controller.testController] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [com.rsc.springboot_test.controller.testController]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:180)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:324)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:246)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:270)

Caused by: org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException: Annotation-specified bean name 'testController' for bean class [com.rsc.springboot_test_controller.testController] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [com.rsc.springboot_test.controller.testController]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.checkCandidate(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:320)


09-Nov-2016 21:08:21.200 SEVERE [http-nio-8084-exec-402] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Error deploying configuration descriptor C:\Users\Documents\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.2\apache-tomcat-8.0.27.0_base\conf\Catalina\localhost\springboot_test.xml
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/springboot_test]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:729)
```

Comment: Shouldn't you call `http://localhost:8084/home` instead?

Comment: @MarounMaroun No. Because calling the `http://localhost:8084/springboot_test/` is loading default index.html page so I think anything after `springboot_test/` is a call to rest controller

Comment: What is the package name of SpringBootTest class ? Add the package details

Comment: @javaguy Edited the question with package details

Answer (score 2):

Your RestController is NOT detected by the Spring container, so you need to add the package details to ComponentScan, so change the main as below:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.rsc" })
public class SpringBootTest {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SpringBootTest.class, args);
  }
}
```

Also, for your test application, you don't need any xml (as we are using annotations and scanning the components using componentscan), seems like you have configured one at the below path:

```
C:\Users\Documents\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.2\apache-tomcat-8.0.27.0_base\conf\Catalina\localhost\springboot_test.xml
```

You need to delete and restart the server.

Comment: You are right. But do I have to call @ComponentScan` for all the rest controllers I define in my application. Can't there be a global component scan?

Comment: yes, edited my answer check now, it is on top of SpringBootTest  class

Comment: Yeah got it. Thank you

Comment: Giving the `@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.rsc.*" })` on top main class is throwing error. Edited the question with update

Comment: Change your controller name from testController  to TestController  (T caps)

Comment: Do you have an xml defined at this path: C:\Users\Documents\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.2\apache-tomcat-8.0.27.0_base\conf\Catalina\localhost\springboot_test.xml ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127729/discussion-between-javaguy-and-satyadev).

Answer (score 1):

`@SpringBootApplication` by default triggers component scanning on the same package as annotated class and all subpackages.

In your case, since main class is in `com.rsc.springboot_test` and controller in `com.rsc.springboot_test_controller`, `TestController` class will not be scanned.

There are two approaches to solve it:

- **recommended**: move `TestController` to another package so that it matches default classpath scanning, for example to `com.rsc.springboot_test.controller`
- modify `@SpringBootApplication` to scan other packages:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {
        "com.rsc.springboot_test",
        "com.rsc.springboot_test_controller"
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, that your `Application` class is under `ComponentScan`. Your project structure should be:

```
src
  main
    java
      com.company
        Application.java
        controller
          MyController.java
        service
        repository
```

And your Application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { 
    "com.rsc.springboot_test_controller",
    "com.rsc.springboot_test_service",
     //etc... no ' at the end of the last package
 })
public class SpringBootTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootTest.class, args);
    }
}
```

Actually the above is the mixture of two different approaches but will work. Remember, that your `Application.java` should be in the root package for all other packages.

And reading your question once again, I would recommend to change the `Controller`:

```
package com.rsc.springboot_test_controller;
@RestController
public class testController {

    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public String home() {
        return "@@@Home Controller Called";
    }
}
```